# Navigate to Python module by name in Intellij keyboard shortcut

Tags: python, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, python-module

Using Control+N while coding JAVA in IntelliJ helps me to navigate to classes.
Is there any similar functionality in IntelliJ for navigating to Python modules.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Install the Python plugin**

Settings | Plugins | Browse repositories | "Python".

**Add Python SDK to the project**

Select project settings

Select Platform Setting | SDKs | Add New SDK | Python SDK

Select a python interpreter

Wait for configuration to complete

Control+N should then work as expected in your project

Comment: Thank u. everything is installed already. Control+N will bring classes, but i want modules

Comment: It should display any module located in your project directory, as well as any module installed in the python environment you selected as your project SDK.

Comment: Sorry, but it works only for classes, not modules for me

Comment: Check the version of your Python plugin - I think this feature was added in 3.4